Can we read k8 container logs using a sidecar container and without using kubectl?
Background: We are using third-party software (SASViya) that has multiple deployments, cronjob, stateful sets, and finally the pod templates which is responsible for creating new pods whenever a user requests it. We just get the docker image and details on how to confirm it and run it and other modifications we do based on requirement.
Problem: With this complete setup we are already putting so much load on the kube api-server so it's a big no for us to use again 'kubectl logs' cmd for each deployment or pods. Another problem is that we have no option to make any changes to the 3rd party app to divert its logs to a specified path.
Query: Do we have any option where I can add a sidecar container that is responsible to read the main container logs? Both container will be inside same pod so is it not possible to simply read the main container logs? If it's possible then I can divert it to a shared location and then push it to splunk. Or maybe the best way to use kubectl logs which will put extremely low load on kube api-server?

You can modify your application to log to a file instead of stdout/stderr, and then read that file in a sidecar container (this assumes you have a volume that is shared by both containers).

The Kubernetes documentation on Logging Architecture might be informative.  You can run a log collector as a DaemonSet that will collect the Kubernetes logs and forward them somewhere; I believe both fluentd and logstash know about the Kubernetes log setup.  This is a little more of a system-administration task than something programming-related though.

@larsks I have no control over the application so I can't make any changes.

I don't think you need a sidecar. instead of pushing logs to Splunk, send them to Datadog and use the Datadog API to retrieve logs. This offloads Kubernetes API operations and provides more granular filtering on Datadog logs not just for pod but you can filter for container etc. More info: https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/guide/access-your-log-data-programmatically/
